# Estimated release date for the dictionary feature in V3 NMT

Tags: dictionary, microsoft-translator, machine-translation, neural-mt

My department is planning to switching to using NMT V3 soon, but we will need the dictionary feature (adding glossary and Do-Not-Translate list) for training.

This might have been asked before but I don't see any recent post asking for it, would you be able to advise when this feature will be released? A rough estimation will do (2019 Q1 for example)

Many thanks,
Simon

Comment: This page: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/business/customization/ led me to ask questions here. I have no idea where else to go then if here is not the right place...

Comment: My bad. Deleting my comment :)

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary feature should be available in Custom Translator within the next month. Please be sure to follow the Microsoft Translator blog (http://aka.ms/TranslatorBlog) and Twitter (http://aka.ms/TranslatorTwitter) to stay up to date with major Translator releases.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know that and looking forward to the release!